# Setting Windows Explorer window as owner of WPF window

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to show a wpf window triggered by an explorer shellextension which is communicating with my application. My question is if it is possible to make the explorer window the owner of my wpf window.

Using this code leads to the error message: "Invalid window handle"

```
var processes = Process.GetProcesses();
foreach (var process in processes)
{
    if (process.ProcessName == "explorer")
    {
        handle = process.Handle;
        break;
    }
}
                        }
TestWindow window = new TestWindow();
WindowInteropHelper helper = new WindowInteropHelper(window);
helper.Owner = handle;

if (window.ShowDialog() == true)
{
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What is the *actual* problem that you want to solve by making Explorer the parent of your window ?

Comment: The problem is that my window is shown, but never activated. SetForegroundWindow or whatelse does not work. The user has to click into the window before he is able to interact with it.

Comment: You probably need the [`AllowSetForegroundWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. Also, read in the **Remarks** section when a window can be set in foreground. This has changed since Windows Vista.